# Error when executing rvm rubygems latest

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm adding ruby 1.9.2 to a Mac running 10.6.8 and hitting a problem with *rvm rubygems latest*. I've run the following with no problem:

```
$ rvm install 1.9.2
$ rvm use 1.9.2
$ ruby --version
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]
```

Then hit this error:

```
$ rvm rubygems latest
Removing old Rubygems files...
Installing rubygems-1.8.10 for system ...
ERROR: Error running 'GEM_PATH=":@global" GEM_HOME="" "/usr/local/rvm/rubies//bin/ruby" "/usr/local/rvm/src/rubygems-1.8.10/setup.rb"', please read /usr/local/rvm/log/system/rubygems.install.log
WARN: Installation of rubygems did not complete successfully.
ln: /usr/local/rvm/rubies//lib/ruby/gems/: No such file or directory
```

The obvious thing here is the extra forward-slash in the bin/ruby and lib/ruby paths. Any ideas where this is coming from and how to fix it?

Note that I've also got the following line at the end of my .bash_profile file:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function
```

I'm doing all of this so that I can run Octopress. I've also got a Rails 2.3.8 project that I am developing on this same machine. This is the first time I've dealt with anything other then the system version of ruby (1.8.7).

Comment: I've seen this error when rvm didn't successfully set the current ruby version. What does rvm list say?

Answer (score 5):

I've had the same problem, and although I didn't really fully understood why it was happening, attacking the main symptom solved it for me.

It seems that you have already another version of ruby installed on your system. The line on the rvm rubygems script that generates the error is this:

`__rvm_run "rubygems.install" \
    "GEM_PATH=\"$GEM_PATH:${GEM_PATH%%@*}@global\" GEM_HOME=\"$GEM_HOME\" \"${rvm_ruby_binary}\" \"${rvm_src_path}/$rvm_gem_package_name/setup.rb\"" \
    "Installing $rvm_gem_package_name for ${rvm_ruby_string} ..."`
https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/blob/master/scripts/rubygems#L104

I think that internally rvm is losing itself and creating paths with the double slash on it, probably because RVM is appending the RVM local dir with the output of some command similar to `which ruby` (or whatever the path rvm is searching for may be). I really don't know why it does that (doesn't RVM work in a system with ruby installed?).

Anyhow, to fix that in my machine I simply ran `sudo aptitude purge ruby` (you would of course run the MAC equivalent of that), to remove the ruby version that was messing with rvm.

If you have something related with ruby installed on your computer, I think a good idea would be to remove them all, and use RVM to manage all your ruby related goodness.

On linux (debian/ubuntu), a good approach is typing `dpkg -l | grep ruby` to see which packages related to ruby are installed on your machine, and then purge them all.

After that, run

```
$ rvm use 1.9.2
$ rvm rubygems latest
```

Everything should work like a charm. At least uninstalling ruby worked for me.

Hope it helps.

Comment: you must got to heaven :), i tried it on my annoying server and works like magic

Answer (score 1):

I just ran `rvm default` which allowed everything to work properly. I fields is right that rvm hasn't set something completely or at all. This has actually fixed this problem for me consistently.